# Как заставить наименьший блок ( с меньшим кол-вом контента) принимать высоту контейнера с большим количеством контента?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FAF2D6;
  color: #302E2D;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: #80C8A0;
}
.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
  .main-content {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background: #C9CCC8;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-content-1 {
  background: #EC5A45;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: #80C8A0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
@media (min-width: 860px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 859px) {
  .main-content {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>main.sheet</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>Шапка страницы</header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <h2 class="zag-1">Основной контент</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... black tag rome red swed growl trown tron refm th t reident apex dont know at now show must go on top scott town row column flex-direction
                    </p>
                    <p>Llkkjf ioh rtjgh oiriot giothoig huthg oiy hgoyt og hh o oiyt iog gotyh giot ogiyt iy ghioyt goiy hogiy toghtyigh oythg oyt hgouyt goiyt ug yog htyi hiot go8y ogt i goit hygh toyh gout hoyh gtohyogh touy gouyt uog og htyhg ylg to hoo t
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="main-content-1">
                    <h2 class="zag-2">Боковая колонка</h2>
                    <p>Nullam ac imperdiet mi. In efficitur iaculis erat id mattis...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>Подвал страницы</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Спасибо.

Comment: не совсем понятно чего вы хотите добиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объеденил и так же в `media` указывать не забывайте

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FAF2D6;
  color: #302E2D;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: #80C8A0;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.main-content {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background: #C9CCC8;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content-1 {
  background: #EC5A45;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

footer {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: #80C8A0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 860px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 859px) {
  .main-content {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
  .main-content-1 {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>main.sheet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Шапка страницы</header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="main-content">
          <h2 class="zag-1">Основной контент</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... black tag rome red swed growl trown tron refm th t reident apex dont know at now show must go on top scott town row column flex-direction
          </p>
          <p>Llkkjf ioh rtjgh oiriot giothoig huthg oiy hgoyt og hh o oiyt iog gotyh giot ogiyt iy ghioyt goiy hogiy toghtyigh oythg oyt hgouyt goiyt ug yog htyi hiot go8y ogt i goit hygh toyh gout hoyh gtohyogh touy gouyt uog og htyhg ylg to hoo t
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-1">
          <h2 class="zag-2">Боковая колонка</h2>
          <p>Nullam ac imperdiet mi. In efficitur iaculis erat id mattis...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Подвал страницы</footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```